# How prove this $ a_{n+3}=8a_{n+2}-8a_{n+1}+a_{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

Define the sequence of integers $\{a_{n}\}$ as:
$$\begin{cases}
a_{1}=33,a_{2}=49,a_{3}=177\\
a_{n+3}=8a_{n+2}-8a_{n+1}+a_{n}
\end{cases}$$

show that
$a_{n}$ is not divisible by $2013(=61\times 33)$.

my idea
$$r^3-8r^2+8r-1=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow (r-1)(r^2+r+1)-8r(r-1)=0\Longrightarrow (r-1)(r^2-7r+1)=0$$
so
$$a_{n}=A\cdot 1^n+B\left(\dfrac{7+3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+C\left(\dfrac{7-3\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$$
and for $$a_{1}=33,a_{2}=49,a_{3}=177$$
then 
$$\Longrightarrow A=,B=,C=$$

and I have see this same problem,But following  for this problem,I can't prove it.Thank you everyone

and this same problem :http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=2144391

Comment: The following is guaranteed to work, but is probably far from optimal. The sequence will be periodic modulo 2013; compute enough terms to determine the full period (as soon as you get $(a_m,a_{m+1},a_{m+2})=(a_r,a_{r+1},a_{r+2})$ with $m\ne r$, you're done) and see whether you get zero.

Comment: Hello,@Gerry Myerson I don't understand you meaning,Thank you

Comment: Each term depends only on the three preceding. Working modulo 2013, there are only $2013^3$ possibilities for the three preceding, so after at most that many terms the three preceding $a_i$ will equal the three preceding $a_j$. Thereafter, the sequence will repeat, modulo 2013, forever. If zero hasn't turned up by then, it never will.

Comment: A faster way of executing Gerry's suggestion is to compute the cycle (and period) mod 33 and mod 61, independently.  If the two periods are incommensurate and if there's a 0 in the cycle mod 61, then you know that there _does_ have to be a coefficient $\equiv 0\pmod 2013)$ and can even use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to compute which one.  If the periods are commensurate and never have a common zero, or if there's no $0$ at all in the cycle mod 61, then you're done.

Comment: sorry,my English is very poor, can you write some Mathematical expression formula? Thank you

Comment: @Steven, it should have occurred to me that it's easier to work modulo factors of 2013!

Answer (score 5):

Modulo $61$ you get a cycle of period $15$, none of whose values are $0$.

Spelling this out, for a term to be a multiple of $2013$, it must also be a multiple of $61$, so we only need to consider the remainders when each term is divided by $61$.  For example $147 = 2\times 61 + 25$ so $147 \equiv 25 \pmod {61}$.

The next term is equivalent to $8\times 25 - 8 \times 49 + 33 \equiv 24 \pmod {61}$ and so on.

Continuing the process gives the sequence of remainders $33, 49, 25, 24, 41, 39, 8, 37, 27, 50, 38, 53, 48, 59, 19, 33, 49, 25, 24, 41, \ldots$ and the cycle repeats indefinitely.  So $0$ never appears in the remainders, meaning no term is divisible by $61$ and so no term is divisible by $2013$.

Comment: The idea of using modulo $61$ has occurred to me as well. But, I'm still wondering how $61$ or $2013$ is identified for modulo?

Comment: Modulo $2013$ arises naturally from the question as Gerry Myerson pointed out.  In general, there may be a short-cut with a factor of 2013.  The question points out that $2013=61 \times 33$; since $33$ is already a term in the sequence it makes sense to look at $61$ instead.

Comment: There is a more fundamental reason it works: the quadratic factorizes mod $3$, mod $11$, and mod $61$.  So we know (whatever the values of a_1, a_2, a_3) that the periods to look at have lengths dividing 2, 10 and 60.  In fact it is 2,5, and 15 for the stated values of a_1, a_2, a_3.  Without factorization the period could be huge.

Answer (score 1):

First find the maximum periodicity of the sequence $r^n$ mod $p$ for $p \in 3,11,61$.   Because $45$ is a square mod all three values of $p$, the characteristic polynomial factors completely.

Mod $3$, $r \in \pm 1$ with periods $1,2$.
Mod $11$, $r \in 1,3,4$ with periods $1,5,5$.
Mod $61$, $r \in 1,12,56$ with periods $1,15,15$.

(I used commands like *diophantine ((3^n mod 11) = 1)* in Wolfram alpha to get the periods)

Conclusions:

- mod $2013$, **any** integer sequence that satisfies the recurrence has period dividing $30$.
- This question can be answered for any sequence that satisfies the recurrence, by computing the first $2$ terms mod $3$, the first $5$ terms mod $11$, and the first $15$ terms mod $61$.

The key fact leading to small periodicity was

> Because $45$ is a square mod all three values of $p$, the characteristic polynomial factors completely.

If this had not been not true, the period mod $p$ could have been approximately $p^2$ (when the characteristic polynomial has a quadratic factor) or $p^3$ when the polynomial does not factorize mod $p$.